# Realloc returning null?

Tags: c++, c, memory, malloc, realloc

I allocate some memory with malloc - about 128 bytes.

Later on, I call realloc with about 200 bytes, but it's returning null!

It returns a valid pointer if I do free, and then another malloc, however I would like to use realloc.

What could explain this behavior (I clearly am not running out of memory)? Is this valid behavior?

Code bits:

```
//class constructor
size = 0;

sizeAllocated = DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE; //64

data = (char*)malloc(sizeAllocated * sizeof(char)); //data is valid ptr now, I've checked it

data[0] = '\0';

//later on:
//append function
bool append(char** data, const char* str, size_t strLen) {
  if((size + strLen) >= sizeAllocated) {
     sizeAllocated += strLen + 1 + BUFFER_ALLOCATION_STEP;
     char* temp = realloc(*data, sizeAllocated * sizeof(char));
     if(temp)
        *data = temp;

     return( temp != NULL );
```

}

**EDIT: fixed. I was overloading the << operator for my class, and had it return *this instead of void. Somehow this was screwing everything up! If anyone could explain why this happen, it would be nice!**

Comment: Are you allocating/deallocating a lot? That could cause heap fragmentation and limit your contiguous memory; though it seems unlikely you wouldn't be able to find 200b free.

Comment: I allocate pretty little - and this happens to fail even when placed as first thing inside main() {}

Comment: Seems like a job for valgrind.

Comment: So, can you show us the code you're running?

Comment: Have you checked the value of `errno`? That might give you some "pointers"...

Comment: I think you need to show us the code. It sounds like you're misusing `realloc`.

Comment: errno is 22. CODE: data = (char*)realloc(data, (size_t)(sizeAllocated * sizeof(char)));   if I replace sizeAllocated with a constant that is same value, it reallocs correctly.

Comment: @pepe `errno`=22 is invalid argument. You will have to post code to get anything else out of SO

Comment: @Pepe: So that's like you saying "there's a problem with my car's engine" and we ask to see the car, so you give us the keys. We need to see all your code. What is `sizeAllocated`? What is `data`? What's the context? Post a full program we can reproduce the problem with. (And edit it into your question rather than as a comment.)

Comment: Pepe: errno==22 would mean "Invalid Argument". Are you sure that ` (size_t)(sizeAllocated * sizeof(char))` evaluates to ~200?

Comment: It evaluates to something between 100 and 200. I know it is an OK size. Also I posted some code.

Comment: @Pepe - data[0] = NULL isn't causing a problem (because C++'s type system gets in the way here) but is a reading speedbump. The ASCII NUL character should be written as '\0'.

Comment: I'd like to ask why you're using `malloc` in what is clearly C++ code. You would normally use `new`. Or better yet, why not use `std::string` and toss _all_ that unnecessary code away? :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo because c++ has no realloc! And this is for a string class, and it would be very stupid to have string class that uses string class internally!

Comment: @Pepe: The point was to not use your own string class. You're either programming in C or C++, pick.

Comment: @Pepe, just one thing on your edit. I _think_ you're supposed to return this from <<, that's what gives you the ability to chain them as in `cout << x << y << ...`.

Comment: @Pepe: Regarding your edit, you did it again! You asked "what's wrong" and gave us nothing to look at. How are we suppose to know why `operator<<` messed things up? It could be anything!

Comment: Voting to close as too localised. I can't see this question in its current form being of any use to future searchers. Sorry, Pepe.

Comment: This code is neither valid C nor C++. In C you can't do class:: and you can't in C++ either because class is a reserved word. Other than that the whole code is C not C++

Answer (score 1):

Since the following comment was added to the question

```
data = (char*)realloc(data, (size_t)(sizeAllocated * sizeof(char)));
```

> if I replace sizeAllocated with a
>   constant that is same value, it
>   reallocs correctly

Now we can figure out what happened.  You replaced sizeAllocated with a constant that DID NOT have the same value.  For debugging purposes, add a statement that will output the value of sizeAllocated and you will be surprised.

Comment: And, FFS, stop multiplying things by `sizeof(char)`. It's a waste of good electrons :-)  - this is directed to the OP rather than WinProg, since it was the OP's code that originally had it.

Comment: Didn't work. I got the constant by printing value to console right before realloc. Not sure if the constant really fixed it anyways - it seems to work sometimes and othertimes not!

Comment: @paxdiablo - I cannot second you hard enough. I had to restrain my "no casting void pointers" reflex from C.

Comment: @paxdiablo Wouldn't that multiplication by 1 just be optimized out at compile time? It does make the code more expressive at presumably no runtime cost.

Comment: @Null, I don't doubt that it _would_ be optimised out. I just disagree with your "more expressive" contention :-)

Comment: So the argument is merely about wasting neurons? ;-)

Comment: @pst: Damn right. At my age, I need to preserve as many of them as I can :-)

Comment: It is very bad practice to allocate the result of realloc back to its original variable as if it fails you have no way back to your previously allocated memory.